# Template base type inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class Box{...};
class MyBox : public Box{...};
```

And the template:

```
template <type T>
class ObjectManager{...};
```

Which I use in some other class:

```
class Engine{
    ObjectManager<Box> * manager = nullptr;
    ...
};
```

Then I extend (implement) the `Engine` interface:

```
class MyEngine : public Engine{...}
```

And in that implementation (**not earlier!**) I know that `manager` should be like that:

```
MyEngine::MyEngine(){
    manager = new ObjectManager<MyBox>();
}
```

But this gives me an error because of types conflict (conversion between `ObjectManager<Box>` and `ObjectManager<MyBox>`), even when `MyBox` inherits from `Box`.

**Is there any way around that problem?** **I don't want to modify** the `Box`, `MyBox`, `ObjectManager` and `Engine` classes.

Comment: The problem with `ObjectManager<Box>` and `ObjectManager<Mybox>` is the same as `std::unique_ptr<Box>` and `std::unique_ptr<MyBox`, which supports this type of conversion, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Templatize Engine and then inherit MyEngine with Engine carrying the template instance of Box that you desire. Something like this: (http://codepad.org/SZMSbCRB)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box{
};

class MyBox : public Box{
};

template <typename T>
class ObjectManager{

};

template <typename T>
class Engine{
    public:
    ObjectManager<T*> * manager;
};

class MyEngine : public Engine<MyBox>{

    public:
    MyEngine(){
    manager = new ObjectManager<MyBox*>();
    cout<<"myEngine created"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
     MyEngine eng = MyEngine();  
     return 0; 
}
```

The benefit here is, if tomorrow you create a new Box namely MyBox2 and want to create a custom engine MyEngine2 for that as well, simply inherit `MyEngine : public Engine <MyBox2>`. Just make sure to take care of type conversions.

As far as I remember, in Java you can declare Engine as something like `Engine<extends T>` which lets you instantiate Engine with any subtype of the template T provided. That is a safer and better way to do it, but I do not know if C++ provides something like that.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without altering the Design in some way I think.
`ObjectManager<Box>` just isn't `ObjectManager<MyBox>` and it is not a base class of it but only the template arguments are base and derived of each other.

If your `ObjectManager` uses a pointer or smart pointer for the "managed" object...

```
template <class T> 
class ObjectManager
{
  T * object;
public:
  ObjectManager(T * ptr) : object(ptr) { } 
};
```

... you can construct the `ObjectManager` using a pointer to a derived object:

```
class MyEngine : public Engine 
{ 
  MyEngine()
  { 
    manager = new ObjectManager<Box>(new MyBox);
  }
};
```

If `Engine` is an abstract interface you could also have an own manager in `MyEngine` and use it to implement `MyEngine`

```
class MyEngine : public Engine
{
  ObjectManager<MyBox> * mymanager;
  MyEngine() : Engine(), mymanager(new ObjectManager<MyBox>)
  {  }
};
```

Comment: I see. I can modify the `<class T>` declaration and I definitely can use the the pointer :) The problem is, even with that (in your scenario), I don't get my goal. Forget about accessibility for a second: `MyEngine::manager->object` would be the type of `Box` and not `MyBox`. I need it to be treated as `MyBox` because I use some `MyBox` methods inside of `MyEngine` (about which the `Engine` does not know). I guess I could always do `dynamic_cast`, but it could have some impact on both performance and quality of the code. Still, thank you for showing me some possibility here.

Comment: @PolGraphic: You nailed it. I don't see an "easy" straightforward and performant way out of your problem. You can use another manager for `MyEngine` but imho that makes sense only if `Engine` is purely abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a wrapper for your `ObjectManager`.
`NOTE` marks the lines which will fail to compile if `T` and `BaseT` are not compatible.

Assuming:

```
template<class T>
ObjectManager{
    T* objectAtIndex(size_t i); // As an example.
    void insertAtIndex(T* object, size_t i); // As an example.
};
```

Wrapper:

```
template<class T, class BaseT>
class MyObjectManager
{
public:
    ObjectManager<BaseT>* manager; // public for simplicity only!

    T* objectAtIndex(size_t i){
        return static_cast<T*>(manager->objectAtIndex(i)); // <- NOTE
    }

    void insertAtIndex(T* object, size_t i){
        manager->insertAtIndex(object, i); // <- NOTE
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
class MyEngine : public Engine 
{
    MyObjectManager<MyBox, Box> my_manager;

    MyEngine(){
        // Setup the manager(s).
        manager = new ObjectManager<Box>();
        my_manager.manager = manager;

        // Example usage.
        my_manager.insertAtIndex(new MyBox(), 0);
        MyBox* p = my_manager.objectAtIndex(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an implementation to support the conversion. This should be similar to the way a `std::unique_ptr` can be implicitly converted from a derived pointer type to a base pointer type.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Box
{
public:
    virtual ~Box() {}

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class MyBox : public Box
{
public:
    virtual ~MyBox() {}

    virtual void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "MyBox::foo()\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ObjectManager
{
public:
    ObjectManager() {}

    void add(T *object)
    {
        objects.emplace_back(object);
    }

    template<typename U>
    ObjectManager<T> &operator=(ObjectManager<U> &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return objects.size();
    }

    T& operator[](std::size_t i)
    {
        return *objects[i];
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> objects;
};

class Engine
{
public:
    ObjectManager<Box> manager;
};

class MyEngine : public Engine
{
public:
    MyEngine()
    {
        manager = ObjectManager<MyBox>();
        manager.add(new MyBox());
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyEngine engine;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < engine.manager.size(); ++i)
    {
        engine.manager[i].foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
MyBox::foo()
```

## Another Example

This might help illustrate how to implement the conversion.

### Example Code

```
template<typename T>
class MyPointer
{
public:
    MyPointer() :
        mPointer(nullptr)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    template<typename U>
    MyPointer(MyPointer<U> &other) :
        mPointer(other.mPointer)
    {
        other.mPointer = nullptr;
    }

    MyPointer(T *pointer) :
        mPointer(pointer)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    template<typename U>
    MyPointer<T> &operator=(MyPointer<U> &other)
    {
        mPointer = other.mPointer;
        other.mPointer = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyPointer()
    {
        delete mPointer;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return mPointer;
    }

private:
    template<typename U> friend class MyPointer;

    T* mPointer;
};

int main()
{
    {
        MyPointer<MyBox> myBox(new MyBox());

        MyPointer<Box> box;
        box = myBox;
        box->foo();
    }

    {
        MyPointer<MyBox> myBox(new MyBox());
        MyPointer<Box> box(myBox);
        box->foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
MyBox::foo()
MyBox::foo()
```